# Unable To Enable Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v

I've been trying to enable Hyper-V on Windows 11 Home, which I understand is not a default, hence the extra hoops MS makes one go through to enable the feature (any way)... I have enabled virtualization in BIOS; checked that the hardware is compatible. Powershell is indicating that hypervisor is detected.

When I try to install from Microsoft Features, it says the feature is unknown (corrected the spacing issue to end up with this error. Ran a script I found online, which "everyone" else seems to swear by, & got the same error.

> ```
> Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
> Version: 10.0.22000.653
>
> Image Version: 10.0.22000.978
>
>
> Error: 0x800f080c
>
> Feature name Microsoft-Hyper-V is unknown.
> A Windows feature name was not recognized.
> Use the /Get-Features option to find the name of the feature in the image and try the command again.
>
> The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
>
> C:\WINDOWS\system32>pause
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

I then turned off the c memory integrity from core isolation & ran again:

> DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V.

Ended up with the same error.

Any help on what I might be missing?

System Info:

> OS Name: Microsoft Windows 11 Home OS Version: 10.0.22000 N/A Build
> 22000 OS Build Type: Multiprocessor Free System Model: HP Spectre x360
> Convertible 15-eb0xxx System Type:  x64-based PC Processor(s):1
> Processor(s) Installed.|| Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 12
> GenuineIntel ~1803 Mhz BIOS Version: AMI F.12 Hyper-V Requirements: A
> hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not
> be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Open PowerShell or Command Prompt as administrator,

Run the following commands one by one:

DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth

DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth

DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth

Note: This step may take a few minutes to start and up to 30 minutes to complete.

After you see all 3 commands got completed run this below command next,

sfc /scannow

Wait for a message that says "Verification 100% complete".
Check if it could resolve the issue and Let me know if still facing the issue.

Comment: Thank you Paul.. Completed the scans as instructed, and ni issues identified. 
Same results after attempting again.